# Accessing the row variable within the function

Tags: purescript

My understanding of row polymorphism in [ML](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13047934) is that we can access the row variable within the function.

```
fun f {x : real, y : real, R} = {x = 2 * x, y = 2 * y, R};
 => (* f : {x : real, y : real, _ : ..a} -> {x : real, y : real, _ : ..a} *)

f {x = 2.0, y = 3.0, z = 4.0}; 
=> (* it = {x = 4.0, y = 6.0, z = 4.0}; *)
```

Just curious if this is possible in PureScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to [update](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Syntax.md#record-updates) some properties of a record without discarding the other properties:

```
f :: forall r. { x :: Int, y :: Int | r } -> { x :: Int, y :: Int | r }
f r = r { x = r.x * 2, y = r.y * 2 }
```